# VT-x is not available issue - Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, virtual-machine, virtualization, hyper-v

Tried to start my virtual machine on VirtualBox after a normal update on windows 10. But getting the issue

> VT-x is not available (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX)

Before the update everything was working fine. Searching for the issue tells to enable virtualization in `BIOS` which I have checked is enabled.

**Virtualization in BIOS**

[image]

**Hyper-V in Control Panel**

[image]

**Solutions I have tried**

1. Turning off Hyper-V with `dism.exe /Online /Disable-Feature:Microsoft-Hyper-V-All` following a reboot. but doesn't work.

Comment: @Biswa I have added the screenshot. Please check.

Comment: Just Windows Defender

Comment: @NaumanZafar May be you've to disable all the Hyper-V features. Put `/all` options in your dism command. Or disable all the Hyper-V features in Optional Features in control panel.

Comment: @Biswa Hyper-V is completely disabled from CP.. I have added the screenshot.

Comment: Did you find a solution to this? I have the same issue...

Comment: @Ramhound I trust your recommendation that this is a duplicate, but I'm not seeing how this question duplicates the other.  Can you clarify what I'm missing?

Comment: I believe I must have confused.  I flagged this as a duplicate due to the answer it recently received.  Given this was asked in Sept 2017, Core Isolation is unlikely the culprit.  When I see "answers" by extremely new users which I know are duplicates of an existing question's answer, I sometimes will flag the question, as a duplicate of the question with that answer.  *Instead of putting my foot in my mouth by submitting a comment.*  The flag was withdrawn.

Comment: This question has had three different answers deleted that all suggested Core Isolation was the cause of the author’s problem which of course isn’t possible due to fact Core Isolation wasn’t a Windows 10 feature at the time the author asked the question.  So I am going to protect it.

Answer (score 1):

Windows 10 Core isolation memory might be activated. This is stealing VT-x !

To see if it is activated check this:

[Check Windows Defender](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7MBb.png)

If you have this activated, deactivate it by setting the following registry key to 0

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\DeviceGuard\Scenarios\HypervisorEnforcedCodeIntegrity\Enabled

Answer (score -1):

This was the reason for me "Windows 10 Core isolation memory might be activated. This is stealing VT-x"

I was messing around with my new surface pro 6 running win10 pro. Turned this off and my virtual box machines booted up just fine again.